# Pointer Memory Allocation Issue

Tags: c++

Trying to allocate memory for the bobby array but it's not working. Why?

I expected the bobby pointer to be allocated for 5 spaces but when I run and look in local it only has one.

```
    #include "queue.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create the queue
    CustomQueue* obj = new CustomQueue(5);
    int astar[100];
    int* bobby;
    bobby = new int[5];
    // Place numbers into the queue

    obj->push(50);
    obj->push(40);
    obj->push(30);
    obj->push(20);
    obj->push(10);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not working, exactly? What happened? What did you expect to happen? How was your expectation not met?

Comment: how do you "look in local" ? `bobby` is only 1. What `bobby` **points to** is 5.

Comment: When you run the program, the locals tab that shows you all the vars.

Comment: Type "bobby,5" in the watch window.

Answer (score 3):

I think that maybe you are intending to do

int bobby[5];

then you will see all elements together in a debugger.  Otherwise you see bobby as the pointer to the value, and in visual studio you will need to type something like 
`bobby,5` to see all 5 elements.

if you are doing this statically, you may as well put it on the stack.

also

```
int bobby[5];
sizeof(bobby) = 20 (assuming 4 B/int)
```

but

```
int* bobby;
sizeof(bobby) = 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your debugger (I'm assuming that's what you mean by "look in local") only knows that the `bobby` pointer is a pointer to a *single* integer. The debugger does not understand the following allocation `new int[5]`. This is due to the way pointers and arrays work in C++, and is not due to incorrect code on your part.

You may be able to instruct your debugger to display more following elements of the array you allocated, but the way to do that would be specific to whatever tools you're using.